# Best practices to write lazy ajax services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

What is the best practice to write lazy ajax services in angular-js? For example, I want to create resource that for some reason should return promise like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule',[])
  .factory('myService', function() {
    return {
      getData: function() {
          return $http.get('http://host/api/data');
      }
    }
  });
```

And I want to load this data only once, so what is the best way to implement it?
I have only one idea and it is really ugly:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.factory('myService', function($q) {
    var dataResponse = null;
    return {
        getData: function() {
            if (dataResponse) {
                var def = $q.defer();
                def.resolve(dataResponse);
                return def.promise;
            }
            return $http.get('http://host/api/data');
        },
        setDataResponse: function(response) {
            dataResponse = response;
        }
    }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    myService.getData().then(function(response) {
        myService.setDataResponse(response);
        $scope.data = response.data
    })
});
```

I don't like this part:

```
var def = $q.defer();
def.resolve(dataResponse);
return def.promise;
```

and also I don't like the fact that I have to write response setter every time I call getter, but I really have no idea how to make this code better.

Comment: This is not "lazy", this is memoized. Big difference :)

Comment: Why u don't use cache? It just load once.

Comment: try to save it in local storage and use it!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't like this part:

```
var def = $q.defer();
def.resolve(dataResponse);
return def.promise;
```

Rewrite it to:

```
return $q.resolve(dataResponse);
```

Not that in AngularJS < 1.4 the resolve method is called when().

The rest of your code can be fixed by caching the results internally in the service in the 'getData' method before resolving. That should not be the responsibility of the caller. So:

```
return {
    getData: function() {
        if (dataResponse !== null) {
            return $q.resolve(dataResponse);
        }

        return $http.get('http://host/api/data').then(onSuccess);

        function onSuccess(data){
            dataResponse = data;
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up your memoization logic a bit.

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.factory('myService', function($q) {
    var dataResponse = null;
    return {
        getData: function() {
            if (dataResponse) {
                return $q.when(dataResponse); // or $q.resolve for angular 1.4+
            }
            return $http.get('http://host/api/data').then(function(data) {
              dataResponse = data;
              return data;
            });
        },
    }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    // use as normal. No need to write back
    myService.getData().then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), this has an option to simply cache the data, and is easier to bind to a RESTapi.

Otherwise you could simply cache the data yourself:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.factory('MyService', function($q) {
    var dataResponse;
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                if(angular.isDefined(dataResponse)) {
                    resolve(dataResponse);
                } else {
                    $http
                        .get('http://host/api/data')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            dataResponse = response;
                            resolve(dataResponse);    
                        });
                }
            });
            if (dataResponse) {
                var def = $q.defer();
                def.resolve(dataResponse);
                return def.promise;
            }
            return $http.get('http://host/api/data');
        },
        setDataResponse: function(response) {
            dataResponse = response;
        }
    }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    MyService
        .getData()
        .then(function(response) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.data = response.data
        })
});
```

Now note that I bound the data to the controller (vm for ViewModel), so you should refactor your template to something like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data">
        {{ item.name }}: {{ item.price }}
    </li>
</ul>
```